# Connection to availability group listener on non-default port doesn't require port to be specified

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, listener

I inherited some 2016 SQL Servers with an availability group and listener.  The SQL instances are set up to use port 30001, and the AG listener is also set up to use port 30001.  When I connect using the listener, I DO NOT have to specify the port--it just works.  I know it shouldn't work, based on all the documentation.  Can anyone tell me how this might be possible?  In what scenario could you connect to a listener on a non-default port without having to specify the port?

Comment: Is the SQL Browser service running?

Comment: The port and instance name are interchangeable, you just need to supply one of them. You are most likely using SQL Browser's functionality to traduce the instance name to a port.

Comment: Yes, the SQL Browser is running, but the documentation states that the AG Listener does not use the SQL Browser.

Comment: It's a quick test to stop the browser and see what happens--documentation can be wrong.  If it still connects, then I'd say that SQL Server is also listening on 1433.  Run "netstat -ab" on the server and see what ports sqlservr.exe is listening on.

Comment: I don't see 1433 when I do a netstat -ab.  I stopped the SQL Server Browser and it still works.   Puzzling.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of at the moment is that a SQL client alias is set up on the client(s).

Comment: Did you try connecting to the listener while also specifying the port? Can you run this after connecting, and show us the results? `select net_transport,local_tcp_port,auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@SPID`.

Comment: What happens if you try using the listener IP instead of listener name? That should eliminate possible alias interference.